# How can I insert data into JComboBox using JTextField

Tags: java, database, swing, jtextfield, jcombobox

I have write program that program have 2 frame one frame to add item and save to database 
in another frame I have to select the item which is add in first frame in `JComboBox` I write that code for insert data into database but I don't know how to display in `JComboBox`

```
try {
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PROCAT";
    String uName = "zain";
    String uPass = "zain";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
    String m = "insert into ITEMB (ITEM,ITEMNAME,PRISE) values(?,?,?)";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(m);
    ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText()));
    ps.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
    ps.setString(3, jTextField4.getText());
    ps.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "record saved");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
}
```

This for `JComboBox`:

```
try
{

    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PROCAT";
    String uName = "zain";
    String uPass = "zain";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);

    st = con.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery("select ITEMNAME from ITEMB;");
    while (rs.next()) {
        jCom.addItem(rs.getString("ITEMNAME"));
    }

 }
 catch(Exception ex) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
 }
```

Comment: I don't know if its me but I didn't understand your question. What should your frames exactly do and where are you stuck / where doesn't the program do what you want?

Comment: sorry pro my english is not that much good but what am trying is to get the data from database and display in combobox

Comment: The guy who answered your question tried to make your question clear. If he is correct, you should think of editing the info into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my understanding, there are 2 frames. One of them is for viewing records and has the `JComboBox`, the other one is for inserting records and has the `JTextField`.

The default frame would be the one with the `JComboBox`. If you want to add a new record into the `JComboBox`, a frame will appear for adding of records.

Once the `INSERT` statements are issued, the frame with the `JTextField` will be closed and the frame with the `JComboBox` will appear showing the newly added records.

You can provide a Reload button for deleting the items inside the `JComboBox` and then reloading the data using the `SELECT` statement.

```
while (rs.next()) {
    jComboBox.addItem(rs.getString("ITEMNAME"));
}
```

And then, use

```
jComboBox.repaint();
```

Comment: is exactly what am trying to do i didnt get how to use repaint()

Comment: @marionjeff `updateUI` has nothing to do with invalidating or repainting the component, these are side effects, `updateUI` is related to reapplying the look and feel delegate, which is not a quick process and should be avoid unless you changed the look and feel in some significant way...